# jQuery onInput recognize line break

Tags: jquery, html, input, textarea

To provide a preview of an entry I use jQuery as the following

```
$('#text').on('input',function(){
    $('#previewText').html($('#text').val());
});
```

`#text` is a textarea and `#previewText` a simple `<p>`

It works very well except at one point: It does not recognize when I hit `ENTER`. Instead of the wanted line break it simply writes on in the same line.

Is there any possibility to achieve the recognizing of line breaks with this method?

Comment: have you ever heard of textareas?

Comment: What do  you mean? Of course I heard of it because I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code from this:

```
$('#text').on('input',function(){
    $('#previewText').html($('#text').val());
});
```

to this:

```
$('#text').on("input", function () {
        $('#previewText').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zevmLh35/)

What the modified code does is that it replaces the line breaks character `"\n"` to `"<br/>"` which is the *HTML version* of standard *line break*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: As in case of textarea, it is a new line character and in html for new line we use a 
 tag. So the idea is to replace the textarea's new line char with the 
 tag. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qh6cepp7/

```
$('#text').keypress(function(event){ 
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    $('#previewText').html($('#text').val().split("\n").join("<br>"));
});
```